# Angular 2 - HTML & CSS to PDF (to be send as attachment in email)

Tags: angular, jspdf, html-pdf

I am trying to convert HTML & CSS of a page to PDF using jsPDF:

```
var pdf = new jsPDF('l', 'pt', 'a4');
pdf.addHTML(document.getElementsByClassName("container"),0,0, function () {
  pdf.save('web.pdf');
});
```

However, jsPDF exclude CSS. Also, the PDF created is a file that is downloaded to local storage. I would like the PDF to be hold as a variable and so that it can be sent as attachment in email. Please suggest what is the alternatives that is available?

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular5-pdf

Answer (score 2):

To send pdf as mail, you would need to do that from the server. So, the best way would be to create a pdf file at the server, too.

If you are using Node as your server-side language, you can use [html-pdf](https://www.npmjs.com/package/html-pdf) to create pdf file and then use [Nodemailer](https://nodemailer.com/about/) to send it as email.